# strip_tags() .... replace tags by space rather than deleting them

Tags: php

Do you know how to replace html tags with a space character using php?

If I display

```
strip_tags('<h1>Foo</h1>bar');
```

I get as result "foobar" but what I need to keep words separate is "foo bar".

Comment: I don't think this is possible with `strip_tags()`

Comment: With brute force, you could add a space after each `>` with `str_replace()` and the extra spaces will get collapsed on screen, but that of course won't work if you have fussy markup like `a word wi<span class='othercolor'>th spec</span>ial colors inside`

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Try this.

```
preg_replace('#<[^>]+>#', ' ', '<h1>Foo</h1>bar');
```

Comment: It's not gonna work if you have something like this `<button onclick="document.getElementById('alert').innerHTML='<strong>MESSAGE</strong>';" />`. Do you have something else in mind?

Comment: I posted my solution!

Comment: Not to have duplicate spaces:
preg_replace(array('#<[^>]+>#', '/\s+/'), ' ', $stringHtml);

Answer (score 77):

```
$string      = '<h1>Foo</h1>bar';
$spaceString = str_replace( '<', ' <', $string );
$doubleSpace = strip_tags( $spaceString );
$singleSpace = str_replace( '  ', ' ', $doubleSpace );
```

Comment: Please add explanation to your code. At the current syntax formatting, it is hard to tell what your code does.

Comment: It's actually a good solution! I don't know why you define a new variable everytime, but still a good one. Explanation: You add a space before each tag. You delete them. You remove the duplicate spaces you created.

Comment: One could replace `$doubleSpace = strip_tags( $spaceString );` with `$doubleSpace = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $spaceString);` so that it replaces any combination of space repetition into a single space.

Comment: The reason for defining a new variable on each line is *probably* to self-document the code (look at the names and think about what each line is doing ...)

The only other explanation I can think of is that some IDEs complain about re-assigning vars (here's looking at *you*, crazy Netbeans) ...

Comment: I would do it something like this but it doesn't explain what is going on so well:
 `str_replace( '  ', ' ', strip_tags( str_replace( '<', ' <','<h1>Foo</h1>bar' ) ) `)

Comment: in my case it only worked after i replaced your second line with: `var str = string.replace(/</g, ' <');`

Comment: @Flaudre That's JavaScript, not PHP :)

Comment: i like this, simple

Comment: Came here to say the same thing as @PedroMoreira. I actually consider the original implementation broken since it does not really "remove duplicate spaces". It only collapses two adjacent spaces in "one pass" through the string. Thanks, Pedro! On another note, if you're printing this out as HTML, then *you don't even need to collapse whitespace*. [HTML already does this naturally](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space).

Answer (score 38):

Preg replace is fine most of the cases, there is that one corner case, as discussed here. This should work for both:

`strip_tags(str_replace('<', ' <', $str));`

Adding a space before any tag is valid in HTML. It too has some caveats like if your text has "<" for some reason and don't want to add space before it.

Comment: In my POV the best answer. Vote up!

Comment: Indeed! Simple and awesome. Thank you!

Comment: This does the same thing as user40521's answer that was a year earlier.  The only difference is this one doesn't also remove double spaces (which may be created if there was already a space before the tag). And it's combined into one line.

Answer (score 9):

I helped my self with example from user40521, but I made a function with same api like php's strip_tags, it does not use multiple variables, and it also makes a trim, so a single whitespace is removed from start / end.

```
/**
 * @param string $string
 * @param string|null $allowable_tags
 * @return string
 */
function strip_tags_with_whitespace($string, $allowable_tags = null)
{
    $string = str_replace('<', ' <', $string);
    $string = strip_tags($string, $allowable_tags);
    $string = str_replace('  ', ' ', $string);
    $string = trim($string);

    return $string;
}
```

Comment: almost good, i would replace the third line of the function with `$string = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $string);`

Comment: Underrated answer.

Answer (score 6):

try this:

```
$str = '<h1>Foo</h1>bar';
echo trim(preg_replace('/<[^>]*>/', ' ', $str));
```

Comment: Out of cursioty - why even bother with `strip_tags` at that point? Shouldn't the RegEx take care of them all?

Comment: @DavidGrenier In this case `<button onclick="document.getElementById('alert').innerHTML='<strong>MESSAGE</strong>';">`, strip_tags will do the job, Regex won't.

Answer (score 6):

```
preg_replace('#\<(.+?)\>#', ' ', $text);
```

Bit late with answer but try this one, basically selects everything inside <> including the tags.

Comment: Sometimes there'll be a space after a tag '>'. How to change that function to detect whether there's a space after the '>' or not. If there's no space, add it. If so, add a space. ?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this will work if you know that `>` won't be in any of your attributes.

`preg_replace('/<[^>]+>/', ' ', 'hello<br>world');`

Answer (score 1):

With the Regex solution `preg_replace('/<[^>]*>/', ' ', $str)`, it's not gonna work if you have event attributes like this:

```
<button onclick="document.getElementById('alert').innerHTML='<strong>MESSAGE</strong>';">
click</button>
```

You need to do one more replacement:

```
<?php

$str =
"<div data-contents=\"<p>Hello!</p>\">Hi.</div>".
"Please<button onclick=\"document.getElementById('alert').innerHTML='".
"<strong>MESSAGE</strong>';\">click</button>here.";

$event = 
"onafterprint|onbeforeprint|onbeforeunload|onerror|onhaschange|onload|onmessage|".
"onoffline|ononline|onpagehide|onpageshow|onpopstate|onresize|onstorage|onunload|".
"onblur|onchange|oncontextmenu|onfocus|oninput|oninvalid|onreset|onselect|onsubmit|".
"onkeydown|onkeypress|onkeyup|onclick|ondblclick|ondrag|ondragend|ondragenter|".
"ondragleave|ondragover|ondragstart|ondrop|onmousedown|onmouseenter|onmousemove|".
"onmouseleave|onmouseout|onmouseover|onmouseup|onscroll|onabort|oncanplay|".
"oncanplaythrough|oncuechange|ondurationchange|onemptied|onended|onerror|".
"onloadeddata|onloadedmetadata|onloadstart|onpause|onplay|onplaying|onprogress|".
"onratechange|onseeked|onseeking|onstalled|onsuspend|ontimeupdate|onvolumechange|".
"onwaiting|data-[^=]+";

$str = preg_replace("/<([^>]+)(".$event.")=(\"|')(?:(?!\\3).)+\\3/", "<$1", $str);
$str = preg_replace("/<[^>]*>/", " ", $str);

echo $str;

// with only strip_tags:
// Hi.Pleaseclickhere.

// with event and data attributes removal + regex tags removal:
// Hi. Please click here.

// with only regex tags removal:
// Hello! ">Hi. Please MESSAGE ';">click here.

?>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I wrote all this but actually, user40521's solution will do the exact same thing with only 3 lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
$str = '<h1>Foo</h1>bar';
var_dump(replaceTag($str,array("h1"=>"div")));
```

Output

```
string '<div>Foo</div>bar' (length=17)
```

Function Used

```
function replaceTag($str,$tags) {
    foreach ( $tags as $old => $new )
        $str = preg_replace("~<(/)?$old>~", "<\\1$new>", $str);
    return $str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you rely on strip_tags for these embedded attributes then that will work. Try this ...

```
function strip_tags_with_spacer(string $html, string $allowedTags) {

    $allowedTagsArr=explode("<",strtolower(str_replace(">", "",$allowedTags)));
    $tags=[];
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($html);    
    $selector = new DOMXPath($dom);
    $elements = $dom->getElementsByTagName('*');
    foreach($elements as $child) $tags[$child->tagName]=$child->tagName;



    foreach ( $tags as $tag ) {
        if ( !in_array(strtolower($tag), $allowedTagsArr)) {
        
            if ( in_array(strtolower($tag), ["p", "div", "h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "pre", "body", "html", "form", "ul", "ol", "li", "table", "th", "td", "blockquote"])) $gap=" ";
            else $gap="";
        
            //echo "\nreplacing [$tag] with [$gap][$tag]";
            $html = str_ireplace("</$tag", "$gap</$tag", $html);
        } 
    }

    return strip_tags($html, $allowedTags);
}


$result=strip_tags_with_spacer($str,"<button><b><u><i>");
```

See http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/37299b1476dccb0631d404a073cf1c88f1cb7d2b for a

Answer (score -3):

First do a str_replace

```
$string = '<h1>Foo</h1>bar' 
strip_tags(str_replace('</h1>', ' ',$string));
```

Comment: I agree.  I was solving for the actual question.