# How to delete a certain code range in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
<span style="color: #000000;"><a style="color: #000000;" .... </a></span>
```

There is a lot of that code in my database.

"...." contains different words.

I need to delete (including "span" code) all of it to my database .

How can i do that?

Comment: You want to manipulate HTML in your database? That's probably better done with an actual HTML parser.

Comment: No not manipulate HTML, 263 HTML code added the posts database without my permission. (wordpress) And "...." contains different words.

Comment: You got hacked? You better un-hack it manually as who knows what got in there.

Comment: what will be the actual data need to be kept?, for me, after deleting all the tags and CSS code, nothing will left. For removing html tags, you could try to find the location of each`<` '>' pair, replace all the characters between them with empty string, may consider using `While`

Comment: <span style="color: #000000;"><a style="color: #000000;"  and  </a></span> are  constant. But all the "....." are diffirent. I just need to delete all of them in single sql code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [strip\_tags() .... replace tags by space rather than deleting them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12824899/strip-tags-replace-tags-by-space-rather-than-deleting-them)

Comment: You need create script and read elements in the mysql, parse html(any library) and remove tags and then update row in the mysql. Exist replace() into the mysql but if not know exactly that you replace don't work.

Comment: I do know how to delete the tags. I don't know is how to delete "....." between the tags? "...." is different words and links..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your where condition will

```
WHERE field_name LIKE
'%<span style="color: #000000;"><a style="color: #000000"%</a></span>%'
```

You didn't say if you want to delete the whole record or edit a field that contains this.

for a full DELETE

```
DELETE FROM table_name
WHERE .... as above
```